# Adding a dependent row to a matrix with LI rows

Tags: matrices

Lets say my matrix is giving me a unique solution.What if I add another row that is some combination of already present rows?I know it would set the determinant to zero and now the solution may not exist or infinitely many solutions will exist.Why does it happen?Although adding a dependent row to a group of independent rows adds no new information.

Answer (score 2):

Only square matrices have determinants. I'm not sure whether your matrix was square to begin with, but it's not square both before and after adding that extra row. If $Ax=0$ has a unique solution, $B$ is the matrix obtained from $A$ by adding another row, and that row is a linear combination of the rows of $A$ then yes, $Bx=0$ has a unique solution.

In fact $A$ must already have at least as many rows as columns, given that $Ax=0$ has a unique solution. So $B$ is definitely not square, so the question of the determinant of $B$ simply doesn't come up.